# Ioc Containers used for MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control

I would like to implement an IoC container for MVC3. From what I can see the four main containers in use now are Windsor, StructureMap, Unity or NinJect.

I realize everyone is likely to have a different opinion but does anyone have an idea which container is the most used and which offers the most features. I would like to try and narrow down the list of four to at least a list of two.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Narrow them down to two based on what?

Comment: Ease of use: Unity then ninject. Those 2 are newer, so they do not lack features of the others. (ease of use = less config)

Comment: Just use one of those that has a prebuilt MVC integration. My favorite is autofac.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, implement an IoC container specifically for ASP.NET MVC 3 is weird. All containers you named above work with all types of apps - WPF, WCF services, web apps. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I think Gordon means integrate an IoC container, not implement.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to use third party libraries including IoC container, I always follow these steps.

1. List down the features I need for the application.
2. Create *abstraction layer* for better testability and easy to replace with better one in future if new feature is not fulfilled by that lib or whatever reason I want to change. (*For MVC 3, there is already [abstraction layer](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt1-introduction.html) for IoC. So you don't need this step*)
3. Choose the one I *most familiar*. Of course, it must fulfill the features I need in step (1).
4. And focus on the product's features and functionality.

Thanks.